# Limit number of stored items per entity in DynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, database-design, amazon-dynamodb

I'm quite new to DynamoDB and trying to solve a problem. I'm designing a table with multiple entites(entities and attributes are not real but I hope they give you perception of a problem):

- Post
- Comment

The goal is to store post and N most recent comments to post in this table.

Let's say Post entity has attributes: `Title, Author, Text`. PK: `POST#<ID>` and SK: `#POST#<ID>`.
For Comment I'm interested in author, comment text and submission date. So attributes would be: `Author, Text, SubmittedAt`. PK: `POST#<ID>` and SK: `#COMMENT#<COMMENT_ID>`.
My items would look like this:

```
{"PK": "POST#1", "SK": "#POST#1", "Title": "Some", "Author": "john@doe.com", "Text": "Post text 1"}
{"PK": "POST#1", "SK": "#COMMENT#1", "Author": "author1@comment.post" "Text": "Some text1", "SubmittedAt": "2020-09-01T22:43:00+00:00"}
{"PK": "POST#1", "SK": "#COMMENT#2", "Author": "author1@comment.post" "Text": "Some text2", "SubmittedAt": "2020-09-02T22:43:00+00:00"}
{"PK": "POST#1", "SK": "#COMMENT#3", "Author": "author2@comment.post" "Text": "Some text3", "SubmittedAt": "2020-09-03T22:43:00+00:00"}
```

As you can imagine post may be hot and commented often.
I'm trying update this table as fast and as cheap as possible. I need to store let's say max 5 comments per post in the table.

So far I have 2 ideas:

1. Read before write: Read comments, compare SubmittedAt, get most oldest, push it out and write new item --> slows down the "submit comment" action(API call)
2. Write, use DynamoDB Stream + Lambda for post-processing, which would require read of the whole thing anyways --> introduces another piece of code to maintain and costs on stream and lambda.

What are the other ways to achieve this? And which one would be recommended?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Transactions are another way of handling this use case.

You could keep a count of the number of comments in the `Post` item and only insert a new comment if that count is below 5.  DynamoDB transactions can make all this happen in a single operation using [transact_write_items](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html#transaction-apis-txwriteitems).  For example:

```
dynamodbclient.transact_write_items(
  TransactItems: [
      { // insert a new Post item
        Put: {
          TableName: my_table,
          Item: {                  
            PK: "POST#1",
            SK: "COMMENT#1",
            Author: "author1@comment.post",
            Text: "some text 1",
            submittedAt: "2020-09-03T22:43:00+00:00"
          }
        }
      },
      { // conditionally Update the num_comments attribute 
        Update: {
          TableName: "my_table",
          Key: {
            PK: "POST#1",
            SK: "POST#1"
          },
          ConditionExpression: "num_comments < 5",
          UpdateExpression: "SET #num_comments = #num_comments + :incr",
          ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#num_comments": "num_comments"
          },
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {":incr": 1}
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

[DynamoDB Transactions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/transaction-apis.html) can support up to 25 operations in a single request.  Transactions are "all or nothing"; either all operations succeed or they all fail.  In this particular transaction, you are doing two operations:

1. Create a new Comment item with a Put Request
2. Increment the `num_comments` counter on the Post item **only if num_comments is less than 5**

If `num_comments` is less than 5, the transaction will succeed and you'll insert the Comment and increment Post.num_comments.  Otherwise, neither operation will happen.

Keep in mind the following (from the docs):

> There is no additional cost to enable transactions for your DynamoDB tables. You pay only for the reads or writes that are part of your transaction. DynamoDB performs two underlying reads or writes of every item in the transaction: one to prepare the transaction and one to commit the transaction. The two underlying read/write operations are visible in your Amazon CloudWatch metrics.

Comment: Not sure I got the idea: `only insert a new comment if that count is below 5`. If new comment is submitted and there are 5 already I need to push out the oldest and insert new one. Having counter in Post entity would help to decide whether lookup for oldest comment is needed(first 5 comments)

Comment: Limiting the number of items in a result set is trivial (query the Post partition for comments with a LIMIT of 5).  This is made easier of your comment ID's have a natural order by creation, like a KSUID.

  However, if you want to ensure you are only *storing* 5 comments, I think you've got the right idea with the approaches you've previously outlined.  You'll need to take multiple steps to delete the oldest comment, insert a new comment, etc.